# Why do I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while trying to upgrade GWT packages?

Tags: gwt

While I was trying to upgrade my project from GWT-2.1.0 to GWT-2.4.0, I am getting the following exception, of which I can make no sense.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
com/google/gwt/user/server/rpc/SerializationPolicyProvider
```

After some searching, I saw that this might have to do with the `gwt-servlet.jar`, but this jar is correctly located in `web-inf/lib` and after all this class is in `gwt-user` as well.

Has anyone had a similar problem solved?

Comment: Are you using Ant ? Maven ? Please specify

Comment: have you check if any jar from gwt 2.1.0 is still being used ? Best way to verify is to delete every gwt jar related. And re-run your ant scripts

Comment: Also, clean the directories generated by GWT (war/mymodulename, war/WEB-INF/deploy).

Comment: Unfortunately, tried all of the above but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me including the following classpath using ant:

```
<path id="compile.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${gwt.home}">
        <include name="**/gwt-user.jar" />
        <include name="**/gwt-dev.jar" />
        <include name="**/validation*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>
```